# Element are moving on hover only on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to resolve a mystery. On chrome everything is good but in Safari when I hoover some element (circled in red) they are moving a bit. [image]

This is only happening on the first hoover. The second time you do it nothing happens.

I tried to reproduce the situation here :

```
<nav class="cd-secondary-nav">
  <ul class="has-magic-line">
    <li id="all-events" class="active"><a>Tous</a></li>
    <li id="week-events" class=""><a>Semaine</a></li>
    <li id="weekend-events" class=""><a>Week-end</a></li>
    <li id="recent-events" class="" style="position: relative;"><a>Nouveaux</a></li>
    <li class="magic-line" style="transform: translateX(103.844px) scaleX(73.75);"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ykgjsfrh/1/ but it does work well even in Safari ...

Thank you for your help

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, rather than simply linking to your website (which could be blocked by filters or antiviral programs).

Comment: The thing is I tried to reproduce that in a JSFiddle but I can't :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding this to the `li` inside the nav in your css file:

```
li {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I wasn't able to fully test this with a fresh reload in the browser. It looked like the problem might have been that the size of each `<li>` was different after you hovered the links in Safari, but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, and it does need to put the `height:100%` in the style. But, we should put the `height:100%` into `ul` not `li` in this case.